# How can I use d3.js filter to assign different css classes to elements?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, filter

For my first little d3.js project, I am adapting the "Filtering with Data" recipe from the Data Visualization with d3.js Cookbook (available at https://github.com/NickQiZhu/d3-cookbook/blob/master/src/chapter3/data-filter.html).

My dataset contains offbeat words paired with types of "animal", "vegetable", or "mineral."  The words are displayed in black type when the page is loaded. When the user clicks a "show animals" button, the animal words turn red. Ditto for the other two types: clicking the button for a particular word type turns the corresponding words red. All words currently turn red.

What I'm trying to do, though, is have the words turn different colors based on their type: brown for animals, green for vegetables, gray for minerals. I know I need to build and fit in a conditional framework somewhere, but the specifics are evading me. I imagine this exercise would be easy-peasy in straight Javascript, but I'm trying to learn d3!

Can anybody help?

The relevant CSS:

```
    .word {
        color: black;
        font-size: 2em;
        line-height: 30%;
        }

    .word .animal {
        color: brown;
        }

    .word.vegetable {
        color: green;
        }

    .word .mineral {
        color: lightslategray;
        }

    .selected {
        color: red;
        }
```

The entire script (it's rather short):

```
    var dataset = [
        {name: "aegirine", type: "mineral"},
        {name: "burdock", type: "vegetable"},
        ...
        {name: "yantok", type: "vegetable"},
        {name: "zingel", type: "animal"}
        ];


function render(dataset, type) {

    d3.select("body")
        .select("div")
        .attr("id", "worddiv")
        .selectAll("p.word")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("p")
        .attr("class", "word")
        .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
        }); 

    d3.select("body")
        .selectAll("p")
        .filter(function (d,i) {

        return d.type == type;
        })

        .classed("selected", true);

    } // end function render


render(dataset);


function select(type) {
     render(dataset, type);
} // end function select


function clearAll() {
    d3.select("body")
        .selectAll("p")
        .attr("class", "word");
        }
```

The only relevant HTML is in the button div:

```
<button onclick = "select('animal')">
show animals
</button>

<button onclick = "select('vegetable')">
show vegetables
</button>

<button onclick = "select('mineral')">
show minerals
</button>

<button onclick = "clearAll()">
clear
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to each item bassed on the `type` attribute using the [`d3.selection.classed`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-classed) method:

```
function render(dataset, type) {

    d3.select("body")
        .select("div")
        // ... more code
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; }); 

    // Adds a class to each element based on its type
    d3.select('body').selectAll('p.word')
       .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).classed(d.type, true); });

    d3.select("body")
        // ... more code
        .classed("selected", true);

} // end function render
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

When setting the class of all entries to "word", you could also set the type class too:

```
       .attr("class", function (d) {
           return d.type + " word"
       })
```

Your css should only colour these items when they also have the selected class:

```
.word.animal.selected {
    color: brown;
}
```

For bonus points, before you filter, if you remove the class "selected" from everything, you eliminate the need for a clear button. Just add `.classed("selected", false)` before the filter.

See this JSfiddle for ref: http://jsfiddle.net/vzmt8ec0/